# Android: Updating List within volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to fill a list of items from the internet. For that I am using volley. If I add values to the list manually, it works:

```
private ArrayList<ImageItem> getData() {

        final ArrayList<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            Bitmap b = null;
            ImageItem imageItem = new ImageItem();
            imageItem.setImageFromDB("http://192.168.192.200/images/q112898055d4-eb4d-41ef-9c00-0069789740c1.jpg");
            imageItems.add(imageItem);
        }
        return imageItems;
    }
```

But if I  use volley, it doesn't work.. The list is empty. In addition to that I have this list for a gridview-adapter. Here is my code with volley:

```
private ArrayList<ImageItem> getData() {

        final ArrayList<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<>();
        final String url = "http://192.168.192.200/getCustomerQuotes.php?9tEqRp93s2t&EsAzJo1EtNM&VuEtfRAPjNU&NTv5hhlsx5Y&uid=112";
        // making fresh volley request and getting json
        JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.e("TAB1ZZ", "url is " + url);
                VolleyLog.d("LIKES", "Response: " + response.toString());
                if (response != null) {

                    try {
                        JSONArray arr = response.getJSONArray("feed");
                        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                            JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                            String imageForDb = StaticVariables.baseUrlForImage + obj.getString("imageName");
                            Log.e("IAMGEFODB", "is " + imageForDb);

                            ImageItem imageItem = new ImageItem();
                            imageItem.setImageFromDB(imageForDb);
                            imageItems.add(imageItem);

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        });

        // Adding request to volley request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);

        return imageItems;
    }
```

Comment: can provide any logs? I mean is there any exception or something?

Comment: I just become the Log from volley with my url from the images:
"http://192.168.192.200/QuoteU/images/112v1.jpg"

Comment: Let's set list data to Adapter inside OnReponse method . Volley run async so I think the "imageItem" you return will have no data.

Comment: I didn't get you ._. @CodeMonster

Comment: Sorry about English. I think Volley run Asynchronous (run in another Thread ) so when you create a List ImageItems and return it, the method will return immediately so the List ImageItems doesn't have any data. The Volley Request run in another Thread doesn't have any effect to you List ImageItems . It's my opinions.

Comment: @AnoopKanyan Yeah, it is in my local network on my raspberry.
And at CodeMonster I make it like you said and it worked. Sometimes it could be so easy, thanks!